# Call a function in view controller from extension Equatable

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, extension-methods, equatable

I have a share function which is called from a view controller, which is an extension of type Equatable. Can I call the view controller functions from the share function? I have a completion handler inside the share function, so eventually I will put my function call in there.

```
extension Equatable {
    func share() {

        // I need some kind of instance of 
        // my view controller here
        myViewController.functionToBeCalled()

        // other code
    }
}
```

I noticed that I am using topViewController to present a UIActivityController. Can I use that? I can't find the function I want when I hit ESC after topViewController:

```
UIApplication.topViewController?.present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**UPDATE**: I passed the reference of the view controller through the share function and it works. Not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Why are you extending `Equatable`? And what is `share()`, and what connection does it have to equability?

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure, I just used an example online for sharing photos and stuff.